# How to change format of DateTime Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, document-library, custom-list

How can i change my date format in list/library columns to f.eks 10.11.2017 and NOT 11/10/2017 ?

I cant figure out what to change in Regional settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create a calculate column and type the format as:

```
=TEXT([DateColumn],"dd.mm.yyyy")
```

The result as below:

[image]